# Windows Setup: Dynamic Registry Keys/Values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

**A synopsis of my question:**

Is it possible to use your own, custom variables (the way that you can use [TARGETDIR]) in the Registry screen of a Windows Setup project in VS2010? Specifically, I need to store my assembly's strong name and assembly version in the registry, in order to register a COM object on a machine without the installing user having admin rights.

I already tried using a custom action, and I'd rather not continue down that road if possible.

**Here are the specifics, and what I've tried:**

Recently, my employer started blindly removing all employees' admin rights from their machines.

I had created a COM-exposed C# class that I'd been using on a few of my workstations, which is no longer able to be registered, because I no longer have the appropriate permissions under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Through Googling, I found out how to register all of the appropriate keys under HKCU*, but now I'd like to implement this in my deployment project.

I understand how to use the Registry screen within Windows Setup, but there are custom keys/values that need to be stored (install folder, assembly strong name, version).

I could use a custom action, but ideally, I want Windows Setup to manage my registry settings, because (a) it's better than I am at automatically removing all the proper keys/values upon uninstall, (b) during the install, registry changes are transactional & rolled back upon install error, and (c) the logic for registry key install/removal/transactions is already written by Microsoft, and I won't have to rewrite it myself.

The project was in VS2008 until today, but I just upgraded it to VS2010, so perhaps something has changed between 2008 and 2010 that might allow this behavior.

So, rather than using a custom action, is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801639/864414) answer, which seems to suggest that you can access the Windows Install "Registry" table within your install project. I'm not sure how to do access it, though. In the past, I seem to recall that you could access the MSI databases from a special external tool (Orca), but I don't know if you can access these tables in your setup project.

**EDIT 2:** Ah, I may be on to something; perhaps a post-build event:

- [Use Orca to edit msi from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886842/use-orca-to-edit-msi-from-command-line),
- [Examples of Database Queries Using SQL and Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368562.aspx),
- [WiRunSQL.vbs](http://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/enterprise/omn/BuildScripts/WiRunSQL.vbs)

---

* Run RegAsm twice - once with /codebase and once without; both times with the /regfile option. Then merge both files together (removing duplicates), and replace all HKCR references with HKCU\Software\Classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done*.

First, create a Console executable that will be run as part of a post-build event of the Windows Setup project. This modifies the `Registry` table in the MSI file that has been built by VS2010.

Note: You must add a reference to "Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library" under COM, for the below code to compile.

```
using System;
using WindowsInstaller;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Post_Setup_Scripting
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect args.");
                return;
            }

            //arg 1 - path to MSI
            string PathToMSI = args[0];
            //arg 2 - path to assembly
            string PathToAssembly = args[1];

            Type InstallerType;
            WindowsInstaller.Installer Installer;
            InstallerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
            Installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(InstallerType);

            Assembly Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToAssembly);
            string AssemblyStrongName = Assembly.GetName().FullName;
            string AssemblyVersion = Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

            string SQL = "SELECT `Key`, `Name`, `Value` FROM `Registry`";
            WindowsInstaller.Database Db = Installer.OpenDatabase(PathToMSI, WindowsInstaller.MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeDirect);
            WindowsInstaller.View View = Db.OpenView(SQL);
            View.Execute();
            WindowsInstaller.Record Rec = View.Fetch();
            while (Rec != null)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= Rec.FieldCount; c++)
                {
                    string Column = Rec.get_StringData(c);
                    Column = Column.Replace("[AssemblyVersion]", AssemblyVersion);
                    Column = Column.Replace("[AssemblyStrongName]", AssemblyStrongName);
                    Rec.set_StringData(c, Column);
                    View.Modify(MsiViewModify.msiViewModifyReplace, Rec);
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", Column);
                    Db.Commit();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Rec = View.Fetch();
            }
            View.Close();

            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Installer);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The "variables" that we are going to use in the Windows Setup Registry screen get replaced in these lines of the above code; this could be adapted to any items that are necessary.

```
string Column = Rec.get_StringData(c);
Column = Column.Replace("[AssemblyVersion]", AssemblyVersion);
Column = Column.Replace("[AssemblyStrongName]", AssemblyStrongName);
```

Second, create a .reg file that contains the registry keys you want to create upon install. In the code above, we modify the MSI database in the post-build by replacing all instances of [AssemblyVersion] with the assembly version, and [AssemblyStrongName] with the assembly's strong name.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Record\{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}\[AssemblyVersion]]
"Class"="MyClass.MyClass"
"Assembly"="[AssemblyStrongName]"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="[TARGETDIR]MyClass.dll"
```

Third, import the .reg file into the Windows Setup registry screen in VS2010 by right-clicking "Registry On Target Machine", and clicking "Import".

Finally, call the post-build executable in the "PostBuildEvent" property of the setup project:

```
"C:\Path\To\Exe\Post-Setup Scripting.exe" [Path to MSI] [Path To DLL to extract strong name/version]
```

---

* This is a little different than using [TARGETDIR], because [TARGETDIR] gets resolved at install time, and these "variables" will get resolved at build time. For my solution, I needed to resolve at build time, because my version number increments with each build.